# How to get page events bypage_id via Facebook API on Android

Tags: java, android, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

> Hi everybody. I want to get events from Facebook page. I had
>   permission to handle events. I looked up almost every site that how to
>   use newGraphPathRequest() function. I can get AccessToken correctly
>   but in the line of "/742409965912331?fields=events" gives error.
>   Actually, while i am debugging, that line give me X symbol. I can not
>   understand its mean and i don't know how to fix this code. Any help
>   will be appreciated.

```
 public void showEvents() {
    AccessToken xx = MainActivity.Accesstoken;
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
               AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/742409965912331?fields=events",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject().optJSONObject("events");
                            JSONArray data_array1 = object.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < data_array1.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject pubKey = data_array1.getJSONObject(i);
                                String pubKey1 = pubKey.getString("id");
                                String pubKey2 = pubKey.getString("name");
                                String pubKey3 = pubKey.getString("description");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(HandledCampusEvents.this, HandledCampusEventsDetails.class);
                                intent.putExtra("id", pubKey1);
                                intent.putExtra("name", pubKey2);
                                intent.putExtra("description", pubKey3);

                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "events");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

> Example event from GRAPH API:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "description": "asdfgasdfg",
      "end_time": "2017-05-06T23:00:00+0300",
      "name": "Etkinlik 2",
      "place": {
        "name": "Urla",
        "location": {
          "city": "Urla",
          "country": "Turkey",
          "latitude": 38.3222,
          "longitude": 26.7647
        },
        "id": "106296429408736"
      },
      "start_time": "2017-05-06T15:00:00+0300",
      "id": "1865054500427241"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTg2NTA1NDUwMDQyNzI0MQZDZD",
      "after": "MTg2NTA1NDUwMDQyNzI0MQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```